# MongoDB Importer - imports all data as one document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongoDB and I want to import my data in Mongodb. My file called `data.json` and it has the following schema:

```
 {
    "0ja80AEnHtP2L5dQY3VthnUsBWY2" : {
      "-LClYVRHxDL0swrpRnbD" : {
        "date" : "2018-10-22T07:33:33Z",
        "sequence" : [ "task1", "task1", "task1", "task1", "task1" ]
      }
    },
    "0lFQht4tdigZ8hmI8Kq54lxaRHx1" : {
      "-LClYVRJ7KYWZjudkhNr" : {
        "date" : "2018-06-03T06:01:44Z",
        "sequence" : [ "task1", "task1", "task1", "task1", "task1" ]
      }
    },
    ... (more data)
}
```

So the main problem is when I perform the following command:

`mongoimport --db dbName --collection clName --type json  --file data.json`

it says document imported 1 , and when I check the my collection I see the whole file is imported as one document.

Answer (score 0):

your sample JSON seems as one json object that's the reason you got only one document.

```
[{
  "-LClYVRHxDL0swrpRnbD" : {
    "date" : "2018-10-22T07:33:33Z",
    "sequence" : [ "task1", "task1", "task1", "task1", "task1" ]
  }
 },
 {
  "-LClYVRJ7KYWZjudkhNr" : {
    "date" : "2018-06-03T06:01:44Z",
    "sequence" : [ "task1", "task1", "task1", "task1", "task1" ]
  }
 },
 ... (more data)
 ]
```

try above suggested changes and then try to import it by adding  --jsonArray in import string.

Comment: Hi @Nilay - thanks for your comment. I just changed the data - do you mean typing `mongoimport --db dbName --collection clName --type json  --jsonArray data.json` or different command?

Comment: Yes I meant same as you mentioned for --jsonArray.

Comment: It still import it as one document with 185 field in it - while it should be 185 document in my collection instead of just one

Comment: Did you remove  < "0ja80AEnHtP2L5dQY3VthnUsBWY2" : > thing as I have suggested?